# Initial velocity to travel a certain distance

Tags: gravity, energy-conservation, escape-velocity

When launched from a planet with mass M and radius R, what initial velocity is necessary for an object to travel a distance r before it gravitates back towards the planet? Sort of like trying to find the escape velocity but with a finite distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$KE_{\text{initial}}+U_{\text{initial}}=KE_{\text{final}}+U_{\text{final}}$

$KE_{\text{initial}}+U_{\text{initial}}=0+U_{\text{final}}$

$\frac{v_0^2}{2}-\frac{GM}{R}=-\frac{GM}{R+r}$

$\frac{v_0^2}{2}=\frac{GMr}{R(R+r)}$

$v_0=\sqrt{\frac{2GMr}{R(R+r)}}$

This makes sense because if we take the limit:

$\lim_{r\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2GMr}{R(R+r)}} = \lim_{r\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{\frac{R^2}{r}+R}}$

We get the the escape velocity $\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{R}}$

Comment: Don't post full answers to homework type questions.

Answer (score 1):

$KE_{\text{initial}}+U_{\text{initial}}=KE_{\text{final}}+U_{\text{final}}$

Set $KE_{\text{final}}=0$